# Trying to Implement a simple API into an HTML document that returns results specified by user input

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to learn a little more about API's and integrating them into an HTML doc. Currently I have found a very simple API that displays a timezone in JSON format. This is the [URL](http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/est/now) for the Eastern Standard Time.

There are 3 time zones associated with the API and the hyperlink changes based on which time zone you select. Currently I only know how to open the link based on the user input. I would like to be able to send a request to the link and update the current HTML page I am on to display the data from the link. I have tried researching how to do this but haven't really come up with anything specific I know how to use. (I'm still very new to JS) Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is the code I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>World Clock API</title>
    </head>
    <body>  
        <h1 id="time"></h1>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var timezone=prompt('enter est, utc, or cet to display information from that time zone')
            document.getElementById("time")
            if(timezone != null) {
                window.open("https://worldclockapi.com/api/json/" + timezone + "/now")
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: AJAX is the name of the technology you use to get external content without refreshing the current page.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var timezone=prompt('enter est, utc, or cet to display information from that time zone');

    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = state_Change;
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://worldclockapi.com/api/json/" + timezone + "/now", true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);

    function state_Change() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          a = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
          document.getElementById('tz').innerHTML = a['currentDateTime'];
        } else {
          alert("Problem retrieving data:" + xmlhttp.statusText);
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="tz"></div><br />
</body>

</html>
```